# How can I format the following console output in a class function implementation file?

Tags: c++

The problem tells me:

"The class should have member functions to print the date in the following format"

- 3/15/13        //showShortDate
- March 13, 2013 //showLongDate
- 15 March, 2013 //showEuroDate

The following in the function implementation file will not compile and give a `"cout : undeclared identifier"` error. I have `#include <iostream>` in the main program .cpp file.

```
// Date.cpp is the Date class function implementation file

    #include "Date.h"


    Date::Date(int m, int d, int y)
    {  month = m;
       day = d;
       year = y;
    }

    Date::Date()
    {
      month = 1;
      day = 1;
      year = 2001;      
    }


    void Date::showShortDate()
    {
      cout << month << "/" << day << "/" << year;
    }
    void Date::showLongDate()
    {
       cout << month << " " << day << ", " << year;

    }
    void Date::showEuroDate()
    {
       cout << day << " " << month << " " << year;
    }
```

Comment: Argh, I've dupe-closed the question, but the linked stuff was wrong wrt this. Sorry. Now someone else needs to close-vote this for it lacks basic research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
void Date::showShortDate()
{
  std::cout << month << "/" << day << "/" << year;
}
void Date::showLongDate()
{
   std::cout << month << " " << day << ", " << year;

}
void Date::showEuroDate()
{
   std::cout << day << " " << month << " " << year;
}
```

Or do `using namespace std;` which i don't recommend.

include also in case you don't have already: `#include <iostream>`

Basically there are standard functions in C++ which are defined within a namespace.
That namespace is `std` if you want to access these functions you need to tell the compiler where these functions come from. You do that by adding `std::` in front of the function. Or by telling it to use the std namespace ( again not recommended ).

---

Read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/) to understand the basic idea behind a namespace.

Comment: Given that the OP is not knowing what he/she is doing, some explanation would be required.

Comment: @phresnel I've updated the answer and included the link where he can read about what a namespace is.